# Port unrecognized in DOT file?

Tags: python, dot, pygraphviz

I am trying to create a PNG from DOT file

`dot -Tpng  -o temp.png`


and  I am getting the below errors:

`Warning: node s1, port eth2 unrecognized
Warning: node s2, port eth2 unrecognized
Warning: node s2, port eth3 unrecognized
Warning: node s3, port eth2 unrecognized
Warning: node s4, port eth4 unrecognized
Warning: node s3, port eth3 unrecognized`

DOT FILE 1:

`graph G {
    node [shape=record];
    graph [hostidtype="hostname", version="1:0", date="04/12/2013"];
    edge [dir=none, len=1, headport=center, tailport=center];
    "s1":"eth2" -- "s2":"eth2";
    "s2":"eth3" -- "s3":"eth2";
    "s4":"eth4" -- "s3":"eth3";
}`

When I try with the below topology file, it works.

DOT FILE 2

`graph G {
    node [shape=record];
    graph [hostidtype="hostname", version="1:0", date="04/12/2013"];
    edge [dir=none, len=1, headport=center, tailport=center];
    "R1":"swp1" -- "R3":"swp3";
    "R1":"swp2" -- "R4":"swp3";
}`

What is the difference here. For what reason is DOT FILE 1 giving errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is missing some information (a description of the nodes). Assuming those are somewhere and have just been omitted from your example,
maybe the problem is that using `node [shape=record]` doesn't work with the `port` HTML attribute. For example, try `node [shape=plaintext]`.

Answer (score 0):

The port positions are "compass points".  From the doc at http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos

> If a compass point is used, it must have the form
>   "n","ne","e","se","s","sw","w","nw","c","*". This modifies the edge
>   placement to aim for the corresponding compass point on the port or,
>   in the second form where no portname is supplied, on the node itself.
>   The compass point "c" specifies the center of the node or port. The
>   compass point "*" specifies that an appropriate side of the port
>   adjacent to the exterior of the node should be used, if such exists.
>   Otherwise, the center is used. If no compass point is used with a
>   portname, the default value is "_".